# Is it normal that CockroachDB Serverless uses 500K RUs in 19 hours with no connections?

Tags: cockroachdb

I set up a CockroachDB cluster for a school project. The only thing I have done is created 1 database with 1 table with 1 instance of 6 rows, but when I look at the dashboard I have already used 500K RUs. This seems like a huge amount to me, but I'm new to cloud databases so I don't know if this is normal behavior or not. I'm just worried I will run out of RUs without doing anything on the database. In [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhOGc.png) the graph of the RU usage can be seen when there are no connections and when the hub wasn't opened. Can anyone maybe clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this explanation is more likely to be the reason:
[https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/serverless-faqs.html#my-cluster-doesnt-have-any-current-co[…]ing-rus-when-there-are-no-connections](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/serverless-faqs.html#my-cluster-doesnt-have-any-current-co%5B%E2%80%A6%5Ding-rus-when-there-are-no-connections)

To summarize, the monitoring console uses up some RUs. So if you have a browser tab open with the console, it will use RUs even if you don't have any connections open.

As that FAQ says, this can use ~8 RUs per second. Over 19 hours, that is about ~540,000 RUs total. The solution is to not leave the console open.

On the stats point, note that auto-stats collection is only triggered when data in the table changes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're seeing is the Automatic Metric collection. You can read more about it on this [FAQ](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/serverless-faqs.html#why-does-my-ru-usage-briefly-spike-when-im-running-a-steady-workload).